# Opening an external website in a new tab/window/popup

Tags: javascript, html, browser, popup, popupwindow

I know that clicking on:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Click here</a>
```

would quit the current page and go to this address, and that

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

would open it *in a new tab* (default behaviour in Chrome and Firefox).

**But how to have a button such that clicking on it would open the external website in a new browser *window*, possibly 700x500px?** (like if you do *New window* in Chrome menu)

Comment: You can't specify that it should be a new window, the browser has final say on that (and it's usually user-configurable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that with pure HTML - to achieve the result you need JavaScript.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com', 
                                         'newwindow', 
                                         'width=700,height=500'); 
              return false;">Click here</a>
```

However, this solution is vulnerable to be pop-up blocked.

As [@Rob M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693275/rob-m) suggested, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) you can read everything about `window.open()`.

Comment: beat me to it, here's a link to the docs for further reading: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)