# Opening an external website in a modal popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, popup

I know that `<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>` opens the link *in a new tab* (default behaviour in Chrome and Firefox) and that

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com', 
        'newwindow', 'width=700,height=500'); return false;">Click here</a>
```

opens it [*in a new window*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49035631/1422096).

But **how to open an external page in a modal popup (centered on screen, rest of the original page "darkened")?**

Is there a nice way to do it?

I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working (click: popup opens, reclick, it closes, reclick on link: it doesn't open anymore. Also the iframe doesn't load).

```js
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('iframe').src = "http://example.com";
  document.getElementById('page').className = "darken";
  setTimeout(function() { 
    document.getElementById('page').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('page').className = "";
    }
  }, 100);
  return false;
}
```

```css
#popup { 
  display: none; 
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 400px; height: 200px; 
  top:20px; left:20px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 2em;
  position: fixed;
}

.darken { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

#iframe { border: 0; }

html, body, #page { height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <a href="" id="a">Click me</a><br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>

  <div id="popup"> 
  External website:
  <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The root cause is page.onclick is register after pop up at first time, then the following 'open popup' will trigger a.onclick and page.onclick in a row, that caused the popup is open then is closed directly.

Comment: @Sphinx Could you post a working snippet? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause is `page.onclick is registered after popup window is open at the first time, then the following 'open popup' will trigger a.onclick and page.onclick in a row, that caused the popup window is open then is closed directly`.

The simple solution is add one parameter to control the state of the popup. if the popup is closed, do nothing in page.onclick.

**To remove setTimeout, there are two solution:**

1. added another parameter to control the state of the popup initialization.
2. Don't make `<div id="page">` is the parent of `<a id="popup">`, so `<a id="popup">` will not be triggered when clicked `<div id="page">`.

Below are two solutions:

> I prefer the **Solution2**, it is better decoupling than
>   **Solution1**, every component foucs on its own jobs.

**Solution 1**: added `isInit` as the indicator if the popup already finished initialization.

**PS**: In the comment, you mentioned close the popup only when click on `<div id="page">`, to implement this in solution1, I think you have to bind the event =`mouseout`, `mouseenter` to judge where the mouse clicks.

```js
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var isInit = true; // indicates if the popup already been initialized.
  var isClosed = false; // indicates the state of the popup
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('iframe').src = "http://example.com";
  document.getElementById('page').className = "darken";
  document.getElementById('page').onclick = function() {
    if(isInit){isInit=false;return;}
    if(isClosed){return;} //if the popup is closed, do nothing.
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('page').className = "";
    isClosed=true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
#popup { 
  display: none; 
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 400px; height: 200px; 
  top:20px; left:20px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 2em;
  position: fixed;
}

.darken { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

#iframe { border: 0; }

html, body, #page { height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <a href="" id="a">Click me</a><br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>

  <div id="popup"> 
  External website:
  <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Solution 2**: make `<div id="page">` and `<a id="popup">` is cousin not parent relations.

```js
document.getElementById("popup").showpopup = function() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('iframe').src = "http://example.com";
  document.getElementById('page').className = "darken";
  document.getElementById("page").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("popup").showpopup();
}

document.getElementById('page').onclick = function() {
  if(document.getElementById("popup").style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("page").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('page').className = "";
  }
};
```

```css
#popup { 
  display: none; 
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 400px; height: 200px; 
  top:20px; left:20px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 2em;
  position: fixed;
}

#page { 
  display: none; 
  width: 100%; height: 100%; 
  top:0px; left:0px;
  z-index: 9;
  padding: 2em;
  position: absolute;
}

.darken { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

#iframe { border: 0; }

html, body, #page { height: 100%; }
```

```html
<a href="" id="a">Click me</a><br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>

<div id="page">
</div>
<div id="popup"> 
  External website:
  <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I had put the `setTimeout` to avoid that the first click automatically triggers the close, could we remove it thanks to your method? Also it would be needed that clicking *inside* the popup doesn't close it: only clicking outside the popup should close it, how to change this?

Comment: Updated the answer, thought of the solution overcomplicated... To removed the `setTimeout`, we can simply added another parameter to indicate if already initialized.

Comment: @Basj, updated the answer, it provides another idea to implement popup modal.

Answer (score 7):

Based on Sphinx's great answer, here is what I'll use to create a **modal popup** displaying an external website in a `iframe` with a dark background for the rest of the page when the popup is open:

```js
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('popupiframe').src = "http://example.com";
  document.getElementById('popupdarkbg').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
  };
  return false;
}

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
}
```

```css
#popup { display: none; position: fixed; top: 12%; left: 15%; width: 70%; height: 70%; background-color: white; z-index: 10; }
#popup iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0; }
#popupdarkbg { position: fixed; z-index: 5; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75); display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
<a href="" id="link">Click me</a><br>
</div>

<div id="popup"><iframe id="popupiframe"></iframe></div>
<div id="popupdarkbg"></div>
```

Comment: Note: SO disables external website loading in `iframe` of code snippets (for good reasons), so don't forget to enable it to run this code snippet (small icon on top right of browser address bar).

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var isInit = true; // indicates if the popup already been initialized.
  var isClosed = false; // indicates the state of the popup
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('iframe').src = "http://example.com";
  document.getElementById('page').className = "darken";
  document.getElementById('page').onclick = function() {
    if(isInit){isInit=false;return;}
    if(isClosed){return;} //if the popup is closed, do nothing.
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('page').className = "";
    isClosed=true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
#popup { 
  display: none; 
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 400px; height: 200px; 
  top:20px; left:20px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 2em;
  position: fixed;
}

.darken { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

#iframe { border: 0; }

html, body, #page { height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <a href="" id="a">Click me</a><br>
  Hello<br>
  Hello<br>

  <div id="popup"> 
  External website:
  <iframe id="iframe"> height=“200”</iframe>
  </div>

</div>
```