# External website / image size when displayed in a modal popup + iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, popup

On my website, when clicking on links, I need to display a **modal popup** (see also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49085573/1422096)) that:

- sometimes shows an external website (link #1 below)
- sometimes shows just a JPG image (link #2 below)

Problem: when displaying:

1. external website in a modal popup, the size is ok (see link #1)
2. jpeg image in a modal popup, **the size is not ok**, in the sense it doesn't adapt to the screen (see link #2):

[image]

3. jpeg image in a *new window*, the size is ok, automatically adapted to fit to screen (see link #3)

[image]

Question: **How to make that a JPG image displayed in a modal popup `iframe` auto-adapts its size,** i.e. if the JPG's height is high, it's automatically resized? i.e. **exactly like it would happen when displaying the image in a new window (see link #3)**

PS: don't forget to enable *Load unsafe scripts* in browser when trying this code snippet. If not, iframes won't be displayed.

Or use this live demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/um2799fu/1/).

```js
document.getElementById("link1").onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('popupiframe').src =  "http://example.com";
    document.getElementById('popupdarkbg').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
    };
    return false;
}

document.getElementById("link2").onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('popupiframe').src =  "https://i.imgur.com/pz2iPBW.jpg";
    document.getElementById('popupdarkbg').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
    };
    return false;
}

document.getElementById("link3").onclick = function(e) {
  window.open('https://i.imgur.com/pz2iPBW.jpg', 'newwindow', 'width=700,height=500'); 
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

```css
#popup { display: none; position: fixed; top: 12%; left: 15%; width: 70%; height: 70%; background-color: white; z-index: 10; }
#popup iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0; }
#popupdarkbg { position: fixed; z-index: 5; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75); display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
<a href="" id="link1">Click me (website, modal popup)</a><br>
<a href="" id="link2">Click me (jpg image, modal popup)</a><br>
<a href="" id="link3">Click me (jpg image, new window)</a><br>
</div>

<div id="popup"><iframe id="popupiframe"></iframe></div>
<div id="popupdarkbg"></div>
```

Comment: What is your serverside language?

Comment: @MunimMunna I use Python.

Comment: check my answer, and let me know of any clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many solutions, but finally the easiest was to use both an `iframe` and an `img` (only one of them is used at a precise time, the other is empty):

```
<div id="popup">
    <iframe id="popupiframe"></iframe>
    <img id="popupimg"></img>
    <div id="popupclose">❌</div>
</div>
<div id="popupdarkbg"></div>
```

and to check with JavaScript if the URL is an image or not:

```
var url = this.getAttribute('href');
if (url.toLowerCase().endsWith('.jpg') || url.toLowerCase().endsWith('.jpeg') || url.toLowerCase().endsWith('.png')) {
    document.getElementById('popupimg').src = url;
    document.getElementById('popupimg').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('popupiframe').style.display = "none";
} else {
    document.getElementById('popupiframe').src = url;
    document.getElementById('popupimg').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('popupiframe').style.display = "block";
  }
```

Note: it uses [endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Polyfill).

Answer (score 3):

If you need to fit the image to `<iframe>` window, you have to apply some CSS style or set image dimension by JavaScript. But in this case images are being served from different domain, so you cannot access the contents of the `<iframe>`.

The best way in this case and even if the image is not being served from different origin, is to make an html page for the image and load that html page in the `<iframe>`.

**image-preview.py**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html,body{height:100%}
            img{
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pz2iPBW.jpg" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

You can make it dynamic by using get parameters in url like, `http://yourdomain.com/image-preview.py?src=https://i.imgur.com/pz2iPBW.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to load images from the other websites you can use `<img/>` with `width:100; height: auto;`  balise.

You can keep the `iframe` popup for websites on an other event. Of course you could detect what content (img/website) you want to show and display the corresponding popup.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/de8ngdv7/1/)

Comment: The popup should sometimes display an image, and sometimes a full website as `iframe`. In your jsfiddle, the first link is broken because the img can't load a website anymore, do you see what I mean?

Comment: Then keep `iframe` for websites and `img` for images. I updated my answer and fiddle.

Comment: Yes that's why I finally used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49318105/1422096).

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you need to sometimes display an image but in an iframe?

Without an iframe, here is one way you could do it using `background-image`:

https://jsfiddle.net/um2799fu/8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With a hardcoded URL in `background-image` in CSS, then it's not dynamic: the page/image that the popup should display cannot change (it could but one would need to use JS change CSS, and I think it doesn't solve the problem anyway). [In your jsfiddle, the two first links just display a fixed once-for-all JPG with CSS].

Answer (score 0):

You can use width only for that

```
width: 100%;
```

[Before using `width: 100%;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyBdJ.png)
[After using `width: 100%;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT6aV.png)

Comment: For height you can use height:100%

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide a jsfiddle? I'm not sure it changes something for content inside an `iframe`. Also, look at my original jsfiddle posted in the question: I already use `#popup iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`